# Any easier way to construct dynamic deep nested json objects in Java

Tags: java, json

We have a requirement to construct Json dynamically, whose structure we may not know at compile time. This structure could have deep nested hierarchy.

Constructing deep nested objects many times (across the app) is a overhead from any of the current toolset (jackson, gson, json simple etc).

We have written a custom class which encapsulates Gson JsonObject/JsonArray/JsonElement and exposes easy to use interface.

Wondering if there is any better way to manage this complexity?

Here are examples of usage (or similar).

```
JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter();
writer.write("foo.bar", "bob");
```

Should result in

```
{"foo":{"bar":"bob"}}
```

Or

```
JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter();
writer.write("foo.bar[0]", "bob");
```

Should result in

```
{"foo":{"bar":["bob"]}}
```

Or

```
JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter();
writer.write("foo.bar[0].alice", "bob");
```

Should result in

```
{"foo":{"bar":[{"alice":"bob"}]}}
```

Comment: HI Pillar, I'd understand on the guidelines. Should I edit the question to from problem and solution centric than asking for library?

Comment: @pillar edited the question. Hope it meets the guidelines.

Comment: I assume the construction must be incremental, or you could use actual JSON. But it's very unclear what you're asking. You haven't included your implementation, so it's presumably not about complexity or performance. The path syntax is pretty clear and intuitive, so what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Sorry for being not clear. Custom implementation is not handling all of the example use cases. It does only "foo.bar" example. We could write all use cases but we could leverage some way of doing this without having to implement ourselves, would be nice.

Comment: `{"foo":{"bar":["alice":"bob"]}}` is not valid JSON.

Comment: Updated the sample json to fix typo